# BufferedReader - count lines containing a string

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am using a .txt file that contains: "Hello world\nHow are you doing this day?" I want to count whether a line contains a string or not, as well as the total number of lines. I use:

```
File file = new File(file_Path);
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        j++;
        if (line.contains("o")) { //<----------
            i++;
        }
    }
System.out.print("Lines containing the string: " + i + " of total lines " + j-1);
```

As I run and test line.contains("o"), it prints 2 lines containing "o", which is correct as well as 2 total lines. As I run line.contains("world"), it prints 0 lines which is wrong but gives 2 lines total. But what do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have "world" rather than "World"? Please provide a short but complete program *and* text file that demonstrate the problem together.

Comment: try to print output and paste it here

Comment: Why `j-1` instead of `j`? Why naming these variables i and j instead of `matchingLineCount` and `totalLineCount`?

Comment: No, it is "world". Have tried with different words, none of them work. If I use j it prints 3 lines total for somer reason

Comment: it worked fine for me. j maybe printing as 3 because your text may contain a new line which is blank.

Comment: Are you sure there are not 3 lines? any 'invisible' characters occupying a third line? space etc...

Comment: Nothing, not even a spare line...

Comment: Add `print` inside `while` loop and check if you are reading the right file :)

Answer (score 1):

I tested it with a `StringReader`,

```
String str = "Hello world\nHow are you doing this day?";
StringReader sr = new StringReader(str);
try {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sr);
  String line;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    j++;
    if (line.contains("world")) { // <----------
      i++;
    }
  }
  System.out
      .println("Lines containing the string: " + i
          + " of total lines " + j);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your file contents must not be what you think because I get

```
Lines containing the string: 1 of total lines 2
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others answers and comments, I also think you may not be reading the file you think you are... (*Relax it happens to everyone from time to time*)

But, also it could be the encoder of the file or the version of the jdk you have, maybe if you could answer:

1. What did you use to create the file?
2. What OS you are running
   this?
3. What JDK are you using?

It could clarify what may have happened

Just for you to know, I ran the same code you have using jdk8 and worked fine for me.

As follows the test I did:

**1) I put your code in a function:**

```
int countLines(String filename, String wording) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    String line;
    int rowsWithWord = 0;
    int totalRows = 0;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            totalRows++;
            if (line.contains(wording)) {
                rowsWithWord++;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Counting: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Found %s rows in %s total rows", rowsWithWord, totalRows));
    return rowsWithWord;
}
```

**2) and ran the following unit test**

```
@Test
public void testFile() {

    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\TEMP\\DELETE\\Hello.txt"));
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {
        writer.write("Hello world\nHow are you doing this day?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing... " + e);
    }

    int countO = fileUtils.countLines("C:\\TEMP\\DELETE\\Hello.txt", "o");
    Assert.assertEquals("It did not find 2 lines with the letters = o", 2, countO);
    int countWorld = fileUtils.countLines("C:\\TEMP\\DELETE\\Hello.txt", "world");
    Assert.assertEquals("It did not find 1 line with the word = world", 1, countWorld);

}
```

And I got the expected result:

> Found 2 rows in 2 total rows
>
> Found 1 rows in 2 total rows